# Get Windows 7/8 Taskbar Progress - Java

Tags: java, taskbar

In Windows 7/8 on certain apps, on the taskbar, I would like to show the progress of a task that is running in that application. Is there a way, in Java, to retrieve that progress from a running application?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think there is a java-only way to do that, but I do know what you are talking about.  [This thing, right](http://i.imgur.com/DehLX5t.png)?

Comment: You need to provide a JNI/JNA bridge which allows you access to the native OS APIs.  There is a 3rd party library which can do this, but you will pay through the teeth for it...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Alright. Thanks. Let me know if you find a free alternative

Comment: SWT can do this (of course using native components), but it is certainly not very straightforward...